# I'm passing php variables to javascript. Is there a better way to structure this?

Tags: php, javascript, styles

So I'm writing a webpage that has a series of slot machines. You press on a particular slot machine and it tells you how much you won (or lost). I want to change these values a lot so I'm reading them in from a file using php so I can easily change the file to change the behaviour of the slot machines. (the file is just a bunch of numbers, eg "14,-3,6,9,-12,etc"

Now the way the slot machine works, as you can imagine, is that when you press on the machine, a value appears on the slot machine indicating what payout you get. And then a running total is updated by adding the value that just appeared in the slot machine. I am using javascript to achieve this affect. But in order to change the value of elements on the page, I need to know what to replace the elements by. So I'm thinking of sending all the data through to the javascript side of things.

But I've read many times that this is bad practice, and people usually ask "What are you really trying to do?". So this is what I'm really trying to do, manipulate values on a page, based on values in a file on the server. Is there a proper way to achieve this?

Comment: In one easy word I would say: [Smarty](http://www.smarty.net/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The better way is of course AJAX. You will be able to use the server values and update page content simultaneously. I would prefer using AJAX with JQuery as it takes care of cross browser issues and makes it easier to bring data from server as well. Here are some fairly simple tutorials about using AJAX with JQuery: http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ajax_intro.asp

Answer (score 0):

I am not clear how exactly your site works. But I think you can use ajax to do this.

When a user click a machine, javascript send a request "in the background". That is, using ajax. And then you can get the data returned by this request. Then you update data on your page. Have a look at Jquery ajax.